# Объединение в списке 2 элементов в 1

Tags: python, list

Есть список

```
a = ['a' , 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Мне нужно получить

```
a = ['ab', 'cd']
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
def main():
    a = ['a' , 'b', 'c', 'd']
    result = [a[i] + a[i+1] for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
['ab', 'cd']
```